# Transfering Demi Style spells to D&D

Tags: dnd-5e, final-fantasy-rpg

I am trying to fill out a full roster of spells to make D&D feel more like final fantasy games. Is there any suggestions on a good way to implement [Demi](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_(ability)) style spells into D&D to maintain relative balance compared to other spells. 
eg. costs, limits, drawbacks.

Currently I am thinking 1/4 of enemy creature health up to max of another spell of same rank: eg. camparing to Fireball: 8d6 -> Maximum for Demi spell is 48 damage.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! I see you've taken the [tour] already. One important thing to note is that the site doesn't do too well with idea generation, so as currently written your question might be closed. I think if you focus in on your last paragraph, we can help you more. Which class(es) were you thinking would get such spells, and when?

Comment: Which Demi version are you nterested in? And what is the corresponding spell level that you want to assign to this spell?

Comment: @SirTechSpec I wasn't aware of this and it was more of a world building question.

Comment: I was thinking it would be a wizard spell dealing 1/4 or 1/2 damage and spell level relating to damage potential would be the main restricting variable we could discuss. Looking for other suggestions on what could make percentage based spells work in D&D setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to design a spell which deals damage accordingly to the target's maximum HP (e.g., 1/4 maximum HP, or 1/2 maximum HP). In this case, the power of this spell would depend both on the fraction you choose and the target's maximum HP.

The first is not a problem: given the spell level you can choose a fraction that best suits that level. Some spells increase their damage if you decide to cast them with higher slots. In this case, you can allow different fractions according to the used slot.

The issue with this spell is the second point: casting the spell on a goblin and on an ancient dragon would produce very different amount of damage (becoming an OP spell in the second case). Indeed, if I remember correctly, even in FF this spell would not work with powerful creatures. You can fix this by limiting the spell as in *Power Word Kill*: the spell works only on creatures with a maximum HP less than some number.

In conclusion, I would design something like this: the fraction changes along with the chosen slot (e.g. 1/5, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2) and the spell can be cast only on creatures whose maximum HP is less than X. You can also introduce a Saving Throw in order to add balance to the spell.

I think that this requires some testing and tuning, because the risk of having something OP/UP is pretty high.

Comment: Perfect clear up of question, but I dislike the idea of a hard cap that [Power Word: Kill](http://engl393-dnd5th.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Word_Kill) seems to have, not working on creatures above 101hp feels like a dead spell for big battles. That is why I would look for a dynamic boundary and an effect above that boundary anyway.(`min( HP/4 , Boundary/4 )`) Would those be good additions to the above system?

Comment: It could be, but you have to choose very carefully the spell level and the boundary. Think about the following example. Fireball deals 24 damage on average at level 3. If you choose that boundary and your Demi spell is level 3, Fireball is preferable against a goblin, and both spells would have the same effect against an ancient dragon (both dealing 24 damages). Then, why should a PC learn Demi?

Comment: Ahh let me clarify I was saying in my initial paragraph max damage for a demi 1/4 could be equal to max damage of a fireball(48damage), not average damage. (equivallent to setting the `Boundary` to 200hp in the above comment) Does that sound like a reasonable way of calculating a `Boundary`? Then PC would learn demi against big creatures and other spells against small creatures, and that would be the balancing problem.